# How to get a 80% percentage of a plot instead of a dataset?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have my signal's frequency distribution plot in a specific time range. What I want to do is to get its main frequency value by getting a percentage value of 80% about this plot.

[image]

As the plot shows, the y-axis value can be treated as occurrence frequency of the corresponding x-axis value. So how can I get a percentage value like 75% or 80% of this plot?

Comment: As per my understanding, you're asking how to find the values of `x` and `y` for which `y` has 75% or 80% of its maximum value. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: yes@ Sardar_Usama

Comment: Does that 75% or 80% value exist in your data? If yes then you can just find the index of that value and get the value of `x` using that index. If no, you would need something like `interp1`.  It would be better if you provide your inputs and expected output. See how to create a [MCVE]